# How to have multiple projects running at the same time on docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker and having trouble working with multiple projects since they all run on the same port.

My docker-compose.yml:

[image]

My ../backend-web/Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

My nginx.conf:
[image]

And my .env file from where the ports are loaded:

```
DB_HOST=database-service
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

BACKEND_PORT=443
DB_PORT=3306
REDIS_PORT=6379
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG=true
```

Now this all works when I do docker-compose up, I can access https://localhost, but I want to have more than 1 projects, when i try to use same docker compose file for other projects it does not work because it uses the same port. I tried changing the 443 to 444 and mysql port to 3307 but then it does not load https://localhost:444.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I briefly worked with docker, but remember in some instances you have to rebuild container. Try `docker-compose up --build` after changing the port?

Comment: Thank you, I think that did the trick. At least now I'm getting a different error which I can try to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use local domain for each project than port. Just keep a proxy container running *(such as traefik)*, we can `docker-compose up` any projects an use port 80 default with a 
 local domain like this: `project1.localhost`, `project2.localhost`...

You can find here for more references:

- https://github.com/lbngoc/devbox (proxy container)
- https://github.com/lbngoc/wp-boilerplate (per project)